# ImageDataGenerator how to change the range of the rotation?

Tags: database, image, keras, image-preprocessing

It is possible to do a roation between $theta_{min}$ and $theta_{max}$?

ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=90) rotate the images with a random angle between 0 and 90 degrees it is possible for example to rotate between 50 and 60 degrees?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, Didier is right, 'rotation_range=90' means randomly rotate between [-90,90].

If you want to rotate for a fixed angle, I think you should try manually writing a function, which is corresponding to the parameter 'preprocessing_function' in ImageDataGenerator.

'preprocessing_function' could actually perform a lot of transforms, much flexible!

Hope this could help you!

Answer (score 0):

In keras, ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=90) does not rotate images with random angles between 0 degree and 90 degree. The random angle range is -90 degree and 90 degree.

`# from ..../Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/keras/preprocessing/image.py
if self.rotation_range:
    theta = np.deg2rad(np.random.uniform(-self.rotation_range, self.rotation_range))
else:
    theta = 0`

What you want may be `ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=20)` to random rotate images with random angles between -20 degree and 20 degree.